# How to use environment variable on relative path on Visual Studio C++ 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am including few cpp files from mongodb source package on my VC++ project, the problem when I add the files, the Relative Path looks like this:

```
..\..\..\..\..\mongodbsrc\src\third_party\boost\libs\filesystem\v3\src\codecvt_error_category.cpp
```

If I check that into version control, my colleague might place the library source package on a different relative path

I tried using environment variable `$(MONGO_SRC_HOME)` but Visual Studio force-escapes it like this

```
%24%28MONGO_SRC_HOME%29\mongodbsrc\src\third_party\boost\libs\filesystem\v3\src\codecvt_error_category.cpp
```

This has been identified as a bug but never fixed (closed as deferred): http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/688249/project-files-does-not-support-environment-variables-in-its-relative-path

Is there any alternative I have?

Comment: We are just adding include path to VC++ Directories on each developer machine.

Comment: Ah you're right VC++ Directories can accept environment variable, and the relative path on each file is augmented from it. Thanks!